# Why does Henry Rollins only wear two colors of clothing?

Tags: meaning

Any time I have seen Henry Rollins post-Black Flag, he is either wearing all black, or black and gray clothes with no logos. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: He likes the color black?  I mean, take a look here: [Henry Rollins Google Images](https://www.google.com/search?q=henry+rollins+fashion&safe=active&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-Address&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CB0QsARqFQoTCKjo8uPc5cgCFcUVHgodx8QJIg&biw=1196&bih=662).  He's got some black, some white, some blue, some gray, some olive...  Khakis...  Jeans...  He wears what he's comfortable in, and what he feels makes him look best.

Comment: I agree with Johnny Bones. There isn't any complex, superstitious, prophetic reason behind what Rollins decides to wear. We, as an audience, as observers, can grasp a glimpse of character by what he wears, but this judgement is the same for everyone who wears clothes. I wear Pink Floyd shirts because I like Pink Floyd. Rollins wears black because he likes black. Or... he's really an alien trying to mask his appearance in black shirts and Khakis. ;)

Comment: How is this a question about music?

Comment: @reinierpost This site is "Music Fans", and has (so far) not been just about the music itself - we have had questions so far relating to musicians, record labels, equipment, techniques, terminology... legal issues... and even health and safety.

Answer (score 3):

In a [2010 article in Philadelphia Weekly](http://www.philadelphiaweekly.com/music/Superstar-Radvice-Henry-Rollins.html#ixzz3vqVwixuc), Henry Rollins spoke about his wardrobe when asked by a reader "Do you have any good fashion tips?". He responded:

> Are you fucking kidding me? I’ve spent the better part of my adult life being seen in public with little more than a pair of black shorts. I’m like Richard Simmons except way more buff and way more straight. Getting dressed up means wearing a black T-shirt and some really basic dark pants. If that gets me into the What Not To Wear Hall of Shame, so be it. Fuck clothes. The more time you spend worrying about clothes, the less time you have to grab life by the balls. You ever see a cheetah obsess over scarves and pocket squares? No. You see a cheetah bolt 70 miles an hour to take down a gazelle and shred it to fucking pieces. Be the cheetah.

This is contrasted on with his views on shoes, taken from an [interview with MadeMan.com](http://www.mademan.com/man-of-the-moment-henry-rollins/). He was asked "What item of clothing or gear do you never leave home without?" He responded:

> I travel a lot and never go on the road without boots and running shoes. I learned from my father who was WWII-era Army guy that if you don’t take care of your feet you’re not going anywhere. I’m wearing Danner brand—solid, high-quality boots. A lot of SWAT and military guys wear them.

Now this is obviously my interpretation of two isolated thoughts of Henry Rollins, but I think he just thinks that fancy clothes and "scarves and pocket squares" give you nothing more than a plain black shirt and a dark pair of pants. Shoes, on the other hand, are different; comfortable or functional shoes help take care of your feet.

Could his views on clothes be interpreted as a statement of some kind? Against the fashion industry maybe? Probably not. I think he just isn't worried too much about clothing, but again that's just my interpretation. Hopefully this answers your question!